# Why doesnt [.\r\n]* regex match everything?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

```
.*
```

is short for

```
[^\r\n]*
```

So if we combine these

```
[.\r\n]*
```

why dont we get regexp that matches every string in the world?

Comment: Don't know for c# implementation, but usually `.` in square brackets in regexp means only `.` sign, not any sign. and strings terminate with `\r\n` only in windows-created files

Comment: yes, I tested it and it doesnt work

Comment: @alko that should be an answer :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like most other special characters in regular expressions, when a `.` appears withing a character class it represents a literal `.` character. If you want to match all characters a common technique is to use something like this:

```
[\s\S]*
```

Or alternatively you can use [`RegexOptions.Singleline`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) to specify that `.` should match all characters and just use:

```
.*
```

For example:

```
var input = "foo\r\nbar";
var match = Regex.Match(input, ".*", RegexOptions.Singleline);
Assert.AreEqual(input, match.Value);
```